# Clarification regarding the training status of 'domain specific encoder' in stable diffusion

Tags: papers, attention, diffusion-models

I am currently studying the paper titled **High-Resolution Image Synthesis with Latent Diffusion Models** by *Robin Rombach et al*. Specifically, I am focused on the section **[3.3. Conditioning Mechanisms](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content/CVPR2022/papers/Rombach_High-Resolution_Image_Synthesis_With_Latent_Diffusion_Models_CVPR_2022_paper.pdf#page=4)**.

In this section, the authors introduce the cross-attention formulas in which $K, V$ are dependent on $\tau_\theta(y)$, with $y$ representing the conditioning information.

My question revolves around the training status of $\tau_\theta$. Is this 'domain specific encoder' pre-trained, or does it undergo training during the Diffusion Model (DM) process? The reason for my confusion is that $\theta$ seems to suggest a trainable parameter. If $\tau_\theta$ is indeed pre-trained, could you please explain why it is represented with the trainable parameter $\theta$?